# How to remove static path of the uploaded file

Tags: java, filepath

I have a form on which a user uploads a file and on next btn I want to send a dynamic path of file which is stored in temp folder

```
File userphotoFile=PaperlessFlowUtil.storeFileTemp(accphoto.getInputStream(), accphoto.getOriginalFilename(), null);
```

The following is the code to store in Temp folder.

```
public static File storeFileTemp(InputStream inputStream, String fileName,String userId) throws IOException, ValueNotFoundException {
            File docFile=null;
    try {

        String tempPath ="";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfTS=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMYYYYhhmmssSSSSSS");
            String ts=sdfTS.format(new Date());
        
            tempPath=ApplicationResourceUtil.getPropertyValue("video.base.file.path.temp2");
            tempPath=tempPath+ts+"\\";
            File tempFolder = new File(tempPath);
            if (!tempFolder.exists()) {
                tempFolder.mkdirs();
            }   
        

         docFile = new File(tempPath + fileName);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(docFile);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while closing stream", e);
            }
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                // outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while closing stream", e);
            }
        }
        
        return docFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("EXCEPTION............",e);
            return null;
    }

    }       
}
```

It returns :

```
D:\ABCUploads\Temp2\12072020092459000753\admin-Agreement.pdf
```

I want to replace the static path and want only the dynamic path.
For eg. I want to remove  `D:\ABCUploads\Temp2` and just want `\12072020092459000753\admin-Agreement.pdf`

I want to send this dynamic path to another service for download

Comment: Note that using \ as the file separator like you do means that your code will only run as expected on Windows.

Comment: yes it will only work on windows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the pathName or AbsolutePathName for the returned docFile. The Static path seems to be a property

String tempPath=ApplicationResourceUtil.getPropertyValue("video.base.file.path.temp2");

Replace the path of docFile with String.replaceAll(tempath,"");

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get it into string after it returns to web service in `File userphotoFile`

Comment: By using java.io.File methods like getPathName or getAbsolutePathName for the returned file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little roundabout, but you can use relativize() method of Path

```
Path path = Paths.get("/home/user");
Path passedPath = Paths.get("/home/user/IdeaProjects/SOF/start.txt");
// call relativize()
Path relativize = path.relativize(passedPath);

// output: Relative Path: IdeaProjects/SOF/start.txt
System.out.println("Relative Path: " + relativize);
```

and you can get Path object using file.toPath()